# could not assign value to global variable in package of R

Tags: r, variables, package, assign

I'm building a package which has a global variable, the code is as below:

```
at <- NA 
get.at <- function() {
  if (is.na(at)) {
    at <<- 1
  }
  at
}
```

But when I call `get.at()`, it raises an error:

`Error in get.at() : cannot change value of locked binding for 'at'`

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

1. `at` could not be changed because the environment is sealed after the package is loaded. But it's possible to call `get.at()` in custom function `.onLoad` or `.onAttach` successfully.
2. Another solution is to create a variable belonging to an internal environment as @daniel said.

Comment: Your code works ok when copypasted to R console

Comment: yep, it works in console. But it raise the error when I build it into a package and call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look on `?unlockBinding`, maybe you first have to open the binding in your package before you can change the value. This is the part of the help file in R that might help you:

```
e <- new.env()
assign("x", 1, envir = e)
get("x", envir = e)
lockBinding("x", e)
try(assign("x", 2, envir = e)) # error
unlockBinding("x", e)
assign("x", 2, envir = e)
get("x", envir = e)
```

EDIT:
I am not sure if this will actually work out properly in a package. One possible solution is to create another R source file `zzz.R` and create there an environment where the variable lives in and assign there the default values. 
`zzz.R`:

```
.PkgEnv <- new.env()
assign("at",NA, envir = .PkgEnv)
```

And then you could change your code in such a way, that you access always the variable from the environment you are interested in:

```
get.at <- function(){
  if(is.na(get("at",envir=.PkgEnv))){
    assign("at",1,envir=.PkgEnv)
  }
  get("at",envir=.PkgEnv)
}
```

I just tested it in a test package and it worked out, although I am not sure if this is the 'recommended way of the R core team'.

Comment: tks @daniel, it seems work. But why my code fails? 
I tried to unlock the package environment with 
`unlockBinding("at", as.environment("Package:RLibTest"))`, the result is same. So what is the exact environment that the variable `at` lives in?

Comment: Sorry, I just wondered if it is even possible to unlock a binding after a package is loaded. I will edit my previous post and put there an alternative solution with creating a new package environment where the global variable lives in.